# '/usr/bin/vagrant: No such file or directory' error in the terminal

Tags: git, vagrant, ansible, virtualbox

How can I fix this problem?

When I run

```
$bin/my-vagrant up api
```

The following is showing

```
  /bin/sh: /usr/bin/vagrant: No such file or directory
```

Comment: does `vagrant --version` works ? if so you have an issue in your alias; if not you have an issue with your install

Comment: vagrant --version is working perfectly.

Comment: How would I fix it if there was an issue in my alias? Thanks!

Comment: whats your alias is doing .. show how you define it

Answer (score 0):

Try `hash -d vagrant` to clear bash cache.

Comment: Thanks. But it did not fix the problem

Answer (score 0):

My path to fixed involved reinstalling vagrant and then expunging and reinstalling plugins.

```
$ sudo apt reinstall vagrant
$ vagrant plugin expunge --reinstall
```